# how to hide modified column in alerts in Emailbody

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, custom-list, alert

I have to hide the Modified by  Column in my Email body while coming alerts from list.

Regards,
Phani

Answer (score 1):

You have to midify alerts template. Read this article:

http://www.alectang.com/blog/archive/2012/05/16/how-to-customise-sharepoint-alert-email-template.aspx

And MSDN documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897925(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: thanks use full to me,but i want to hide column only for particular site alerts only

Comment: Actualy in [STSADM -o UpdateAlertTemplate command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd279606(v=office.12).aspx) you can use the -url param to target a particular site collection.

Comment: i don't want to display the modified column for alterts to only particular site as well as particular list how can i include modified by column to hide in this command.I have to do in production

Comment: You can implementing Alert Handler and filter and filter alert sources by value of the "SPAlertHandlerParams.a" propertiy(SPAlert).[Example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/17ffc7/capturing-and-modifying-sharepoint-alerts-through-alert-hand/)